# In ggplot2, when there is a facet_wrap, how to make all geom_col bars the same color when they have the same value?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, geom-col

I have a dataframe `df` with three columns: `TASK`, `CONDITION`, and `SCORE`.
I want to represent the data:

1. as barplots (I'm using `geom_col`)
2. with a separate plot for each `TASK` (I'm using
   `facet_wrap(~TASK)`)
3. with a separate bar for each `CONDITION` (I'm
   using `ggplot(df, aes(x=CONDITION))`)

Additionally, the expected behavior is that, if the data of a given bar sum up to a given percentage, then **that bar should be the same color as other bars that reach the same percentage**. Unfortunately, I can't get that to work.

In the minimal example below, 3 bars are reaching 100%, therefore I expect them to all be blue as per the instruction `high="blue"` but this is not what is happening.

```
Input =("
TASK CONDITION SCORE
GAU   0         0.25
GAU   0         0.25
GAU   0         0.25
GAU   0         0.25
GAU   1         0.2
GAU   1         0.2
GAU   1         0.2
GAU   1         0.2
GAU   1         0.2
PLN   0         0.3333
PLN   0         0.3333
PLN   0         0
PLN   1         0.5
PLN   1         0.5
        ")
df <- read.table(textConnection(Input),
                 header=TRUE)
df$CONDITION <- factor(df$CONDITION)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=CONDITION, y=SCORE, fill=SCORE)) +
  geom_col() +
  ggtitle("Performance") +
  ylab("Total") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  facet_wrap(~TASK) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="red", high="blue")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What'a really going on is a bit hidden by the plot. If we put a border on the bars and change the first value, maybe it will make it more clear

```
df2 <- df
df2[1, "SCORE"] <- .5
ggplot(df2, aes(x=CONDITION, y=SCORE, fill=SCORE)) +
  geom_col(color="black") +
  ggtitle("Performance") +
  ylab("Total") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  facet_wrap(~TASK) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="red", high="blue")
```

[image]

It's not coloring by total height of the plot, it's coloring by each observation. Notice how your color scale was only going up to .5. If you just want to use ggplot for this, you can use a summary stat for the geom_bar to do the summation for you. It would look like this

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=CONDITION, y=SCORE, fill=..y..)) +
  geom_bar(stat="summary", fun.y="sum") +
  ggtitle("Performance") +
  ylab("Total") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  facet_wrap(~TASK) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="red", high="blue")
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thank you! Looks like I should learn about "stat" and "fun" if I want to get more out of ggplot2.

Comment: Honestly I wouldn’t bother. I rarely use them. It’s much easier to properly summarize your data with something like dplyr before plotting.

Comment: Hopefully I'm not pushing it but, how would you properly summarize the data in this case?

Comment: With dplyr it would be like `df %>% group_by(TASK, CONDITION) %>% summarize_all()` (not tested because I’m not at my computer).

Comment: `summarize_all(sum)` returned the expected output, thanks again!

Comment: Oops. Forgot that part. Glad you figured it out.